# Connected successfully Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, fatal-error

i'm just starting to study php and I got this error:

> Connected successfully
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message    'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table    'aliendatabase.alien_abduction' doesn't exist' in    C:\xampp\htdocs\study\report.php:39 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\study\report.php(39): PDO->exec('INSERT INTO ali...') #1 {main}   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\study\report.php on line 39

Here my html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2>

<p>Share your story of alien abduction:</p>
<form method="post" action="report.php">
<label for="firstname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
<label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /><br />
<label for="email">What is your email address?</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
<label for="whenithappened">When did it happen?</label>
     <input type="text" id="whenithappened" name="whenithappened" /><br />
     <label for="howlong">How long were you gone?</label>
     <input type="text" id="howlong" name="howlong" /><br />
     <label for="howmany">How many did you see?</label>
     <input type="text" id="howmany" name="howmany" /><br />
     <label for="aliendescription">Describe them:</label>
     <input type="text" id="aliendescription" name="aliendescription" size="32" /><br />
     <label for="whattheydid">What did they do to you?</label>
     <input type="text" id="whattheydid" name="whattheydid" size="32" /><br />
     <label for="fangspotted">Have you seen my dog Fang?</label>
     Yes <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" value="yes" />
     No <input id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" type="radio" value="no" /><br />
     <img src="fang.jpg" width="100" height="175"
  alt="My abducted dog Fang." /><br />
     <label for="other">Anything else you want to add?</label>
     <textarea id="other" name="other"></textarea><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Report Abduction" name="submit" />
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here my php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2

<?php
 $first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
 $last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
 $when_it_happened = $_POST['whenithappened'];
 $how_long = $_POST['howlong'];
 $how_many = $_POST['howmany'];
 $alien_description = $_POST['aliendescription'];
 $what_they_did = $_POST['whattheydid'];
 $fang_spotted = $_POST['fangspotted'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $other = $_POST['other'];

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "davide";
 $password = "";

 {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=aliendatabase", $username,        $password);

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO alien_abduction (first_name, last_name, when_it_happened, how_long, " .
    "how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email)" .
    "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$when_it_happened', '$how_long', '$how_many', " .
    "'$alien_description', '$what_they_did', '$fang_spotted', '$other', '$email')";

$conn->exec($sql);
echo "New record created successfully";


{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br />';
echo 'You were abducted ' . $when_it_happened;
echo ' and were gone for ' . $how_long . '<br />';
echo 'Number of aliens: ' . $how_many . '<br />';
echo 'Describe them: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
echo 'The aliens did this: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
echo 'Was Fang there? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br />';
echo 'Other comments: ' . $other . '<br />';
echo 'Your email address is ' . $email;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong? Please can someone explain it?
I'm running apache and mysql server by xampp in localhost

Comment: Is `alien_abduction` your correct table name, and that is in the `aliendatabase` database? This also is going to be open to SQL injections you should learn parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was the name of the table wrong...
can you explain me for what I need  parameterized queries? I'm studying by following a book and making tests..

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was the name of the table wrong...
can you explain me for what I need  parameterized queries? I'm studying by following a book and making tests..
Now i correct the name of the table but I got this:
Connected successfullyNew record created successfully
Notice: Undefined variable: e in C:\xampp\htdocs\study\report.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\study\report.php on line 45

Comment: `$e` is not defined in your code; nor is `getMessage()` because `$e` is nothing. The supplied link should explain why you'd use prepared statements and how to. If you have some particular question about it please ask that. Take a look at this page http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php. It looks like that is where your `e` came from but you lost the `try` and `catch`. `catch (PDOException $e) {`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!
I don't even now what $e and getMessage are..
I'm using PDO because I read that it is better to use sqli
I'm just tring to send data from my form in html in mysql without errors that I had by using sqli syntax,
I think I'm doing somethings wrong.. it would be better to do differently?
After changing the name of the table in the query, the data from the form are present, but how can I correct the error?

Comment: Modifie the the code to use the `try` and `catch`, I'm not really clear what your current code looks like. Update the code here to match your current code.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code,
Please, have a look.
Thank you!

Comment: Still not using try catch... Look at pdo error link I sent

Comment: thank you very much for your patience and help;
everything work well now!!